# Java: getting incorrect string.length() after using trim()

Tags: java, string

I have the string `"22"` and I'm getting 3 as length;

I used `.trim()`

What else could be a reason for this?

Comment: You'll have to show us your code, because as stated, it's not possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be giving us code that demonstrates the problem, but my guess is you did something like this:

```
String str = "22 ";
str.trim();
System.out.println(str.length());
```

But `str.trim()` doesn't change `str` (as Strings are immutable).  Instead it returns a new String trimmed.  So you need something like this:

```
String str = "22 ";
str = str.trim();
System.out.println(str.length());
```

Comment: 5 minute response time?!?! Come on guys, we can do better than that... ;)

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(theString.toCharArray()));
```

This dumps the `char[]` version of the `String`, so we can perhaps see if it contains anything funny.

Comment: +1 It's a good diagnostic tool even if it wasn't needed this time.

Comment: Didn't even have the same problem is OP but this really helped figure out that the string was using ANSI escape codes. +1

Answer (score -2):

since i found a reason while formulating the question, im gonna answer myself..

If the string was created by .substring or split, the whole string is saved plus the position and length of the substring.

this apparently cant be trimmed (was " 22")

Comment: `length()` does not return the length of the backing array, and it should be able to be trimmed.  See my answer.